# Why is the header shrinking and creating an empty space on the right- Building a Response site

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to make this responsive, and I just don't get why the header shrinks and creates an empty space on the right, but the other flex item, right below it, is just fine.

On Desktop
[image: On Desktop]

On Mobile
[image: On Mobile]

```
 <NavContainer>
  <div className="nav-center">
    <div className="nav-header">
      <div className="nav-left">
        <p>Français</p>
      </div>

      <div className="nav-right">
        <PersonOutlineRoundedIcon fontSize="large" />
        <p>Sign In</p>
        <PinDropOutlinedIcon fontSize="medium" />
        <p>Find a store</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="nav-search">
      {/* Toggle button only visible for smaller screens */}
      <button type="button" className="nav-toggle">
        <FaBars />
      </button>
```

And the CSS:

```
 .nav-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .nav-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-1);
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is from nav-search style not from nav-center.

Answer (score 0):

Your input element probably have an absolute value like px, so it doesn't shrink. It forces the bottom header to stay in the same length, while the upper header is shrinking. You might want to have a breakpoint where you resize your input element.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly it. I had a width on the input. I didn't realize it would affect the other elements.